# Load Joomla K2 module in an external php

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

Hi I'm trying to load a K2 content module in an external php file. I found some info and examples about this but the problem it's that it is only working with some Joomla modules (custom html and others) but not with the k2 modules. This is mi code:

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );

define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) .'' ) );
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS. 'includes' .DS. 'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS. 'includes' .DS. 'framework.php' );

$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$app->initialise();

$modules  = JModuleHelper::getModules("contenedor-eventos");
$document = JFactory::getDocument();     
$attribs  = array();
$attribs['style'] = 'xhtml';

foreach ($modules as $mod)
{
    echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($mod, $attribs);
}
```

I have this error message: Fatal error: Class 'K2Model' not found in /home/my_user/my_domain/modules/mod_k2_content/helper.php on line 289

The code in helper.php line 289 is:

```
$model = K2Model::getInstance('Item', 'K2Model');
```

Hope someone could help me.
Thanks in advance.